# Error "undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass" when testing a model with RSpec.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

I am learning RSpec and testing the below scenario:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Student, type: :model do
  before(:each) do
    Student.delete_all
  end

  it "roll number can't be less than 0 or more than 80" do
    s = Student.create(:name => "sanjay" , :lastname => "test" , :roll => 0)
    s1 = Student.create(:name => "sanjay" , :lastname => "test" , :roll => 81)
    expect(s).not_to be_valid
    expect(s1).not_to be_valid
  end
end
```

below is the Student model definition:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :roll
  validate :number_of_valid_students
  def number_of_valid_students
    if (self.roll < 1)  or (self.roll > 80)
      self.errors.add(:rollnumber , "Can't be less than 0 or greater than 80")
    end
  end
end
```

After running the command `rake spec:models` I am getting the error below:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(student).not_to be_valid
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: but in my test case i am providing roll value as 1 & 80. then how come student.roll comes nil

Comment: 1. use numericality validation. 2. Don't use `self` where you do - it's redundant. 3. You're checking `roll`, but adding errors to `rollnumber`. 4. Don't use `or` but `||` - `or` is rather for control flow, not for defining conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add a custom validation. Consider using the [numericality validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality) provided by ActiveRecord:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :roll, uniqueness: true
  validates :roll, numericality: { greater_than: 1, less_than: 80 }
end
```

Also write your test in this way:

```
let(:student1) { Student.create(name: "sanjay", lastname: "test", roll: 0) }
let(:student2) { Student.create(name: "sanjay", lastname: "test", roll: 81) }

it "roll number can't be less than 0 or more than 80" do
  expect(student1).not_to be_valid
  expect(student2).not_to be_valid
end
```

Take a look on [Better Specs](http://betterspecs.org/) for RSpec best practices.

Comment: it's working fine now... but i still confused why i am getting error if i am not passing nil value to the roll number field.

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing, you use roll and rollnumber names for the same thing, I can't say for sure what is the problem. It the answer helped you, consider accepting it as the correct answer :)

Comment: yes the answer helped me.. anyway i am accepting the answer but i was hoping answer for my real problem.